# Trying to get cell info from Dashboard

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dashboard

Hi i have the below table showing the project name, its end date, & the resource allocation working on it.
In the FREE BY variable i want to show to the end of the project which is ending first.

For Example. Resource D is working 50% on two projects, in the FREE By variable i want to show END DATE of project LAN as its getting over 1st.

Request you to tell me the formula that can be used to get the info.

[image]

Comment: Something like `=MAXIFS($B3:$B7,C3:C7,">0")` dragged right.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution, however it is still taking the highest date I.E. 10/18/2021. i want the lower date. Can you please help

Comment: Ah, you need the minimum, so use `MINIFS()` isntead.